# Reading data from a .txt file using InputStream and Scanner android

Tags: android, file, text, inputstream

I am having trouble reading data from a .txt file. When I run the app I get an error message and the app crashes, I suspect this is to do with reading the text file or converting it from an InputStream to a Scanner. I have the following code:

```
FileExaminer a = new FileExaminer();
FileExaminer b = new FileExaminer();
FileExaminer c = new FileExaminer();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try{
            readFile.runMethods();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in Main");
        }
    }
```

---

```
public InputStream input;
public Scanner file;
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

public String a, b, c;  
public void runMethods() {
    openFile();
    readFile();
    closeFile();
}

public void openFile() {
    try{
        input = getAssets().open("numbers.txt");
        file = new Scanner(input);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

public void readFile() {
    while (file.hasNext()) {
        a = file.next();
        b = file.next();
        c = file.next();

        System.out.printf("%s %s %s/n", a,b,c);
    }
}

public void closeFile() {
    file.close();
}
```

---

and my Error log is this:

```
07-01 02:10:05.113: D/AndroidRuntime(2174): Shutting down VM
07-01 02:10:05.173: W/dalvikvm(2174): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1cf6b20)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): Process: com.aghgb.pokedex, PID: 2174
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.aghgb.pokedex/com.aghgb.pokedex.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:83)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.aghgb.pokedex.FileExaminer.<init>(FileExaminer.java:13)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.aghgb.pokedex.Main.<init>(Main.java:7)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
07-01 02:10:05.213: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is line 13 in FileExaminer?

Answer (score 2):

After several more hours of research and trial and error I came up with this:

```
    try {
        file = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pokemon_data)); 
        System.out.println("File Scanned");
        // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading 
        while (file.hasNext()) {
            a = file.next();
            b = file.next();
            c = file.next();
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", a, b, c);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening/reading file");
    } finally {
        if (file != null) {
            file.close();
        }
    }
```

This code is used for printing out a text file that has been stored in columns and works as long as the file is in the raw folder. Adding more variables in the while loop will increase the amount of columns displayed.

Comment: What was causing the `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0):

For reading a .txt file you can use this method:

```
 try {
    txtFileRead("filename.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


public List<String> txtFileRead(String filename) throws IOException {
    List<String> readData = new ArrayList<String>();
    AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assets.open(filename)));
    while(true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if(line == null) {
            break;
        }
        lines.add(line);
    }
    return lines;
}
```

in `txtFileRead()` I am reading the text file and adding the read data to list.